# What's the meaning here of "until I would have frailed him"?

Tags: meaning, dialects

> Jewel, the one she labored so to bear and coddled and petted so and him flinging into tantrums or sulking spells, inventing devilment to devil her **until I would have frailed him** time and time.
>
> — *[As I lay dying](https://archive.org/stream/AsILayDyingFullTextWILLIAMFAULKNER/As+I+Lay+Dying+Full+Text+WILLIAM+FAULKNER_djvu.txt#:%7E:text=Not%20that%20Jewel%2C%20the%20one%20she%20labored%20so%20to%20bear),* William Faulkner (1897–1962), pub Jonathan Cape 1930

What's the literal (or figurative) meaning of "until I would have frailed him"?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149154/discussion-on-question-by-soroush-gh-whats-the-meaning-here-of-until-i-would-h); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My 1957 Random House edition reads **frailed** not **trailed**. I'm pretty sure the speaker, Cora, is saying that she would have given Jewel a whipping on many occasions for all of his "devilment" [using  some sort or rod or cane: a "frail" is a "flail", a farm tool with a short stick or rod swinging from it].

Comment: It's in [The Faulkner Glossary](https://www.oprah.com/oprahsbookclub/the-faulkner-glossary-a-through-z/2) exactly as you say.

Comment: @Flumblefingers I very much appreciate your help. I have read those words. But I didn't know the correct word is frail not trail. I have one another question. If you could answer I really  appreciate it. Isn't the word frail an adjective? If so, how is it used as a verb?

Comment: It is the past participle of the verb **to frail**. "I *would have frailed* (would have thrashed/whipped) him.  Compare *I would have **caned** him* or *I would have **whipped** him* where the verb is formed from the nouns **cane** and **whip**.

Comment: @TimR thank you again.